# Tkinter dialog showinfo loop error

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, tkinter-entry

I'm fairly new to python and am working on a CS problem where I have to design a simple number guessing game. The game must also contain a Tkinter Label widget that explains the rules of the game (pick a number between 1 - 100), an Entry widget that takes the users' guess, and a button to call a method within the class that 1) Determines if the guess is higher or lower than a 'secret' randint 2) Guide the user towards the correct by guessing higher or lower, and 3) Congratulate the user once they get the correct answer.

I keep running into an error after my conditional where the showinfo dialog box infinitely loops. I can't figure out where I am going wrong, but here is my code where I start by importing the following:

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, END
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class Game(Frame):
    'A guessing game where a user picks a number from 1 - 100'
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Label(self, text = "Pick an integer from 1 - 100").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.answer = Entry(self, width=20)
        self.answer.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Button(self, text='Enter', command = self.compute).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    def compute(self):
        secret = randint(1, 100)
        answer = int(self.answer.get())
        while secret != answer:
            if answer > secret:
                showinfo(message='Guess a lower integer')
                self.answer.delete(0, END)
            else:
                showinfo(message='Guess a higher integer')
                self.answer.delete(0, END)
        showinfo(message='You are correct!')
```

If anyone can explain why I am running into the loop I will likely be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once you enter the *while* loop because of the satisfied condition `secret != answer`, you won't exit, because the statement will continue to be evaluate *True*, that's why the dialog continues to show up.

To solve this, you can for example put a `break` after the call to `showinfo`:

```
while secret != answer:
    if answer > secret:
        showinfo(message='Guess a lower integer')
        self.answer.delete(0, END)
        break
    else:
        showinfo(message='Guess a higher integer')
        self.answer.delete(0, END)
        break
showinfo(message='You are correct!')
```

Note the last `showinfo` will always be executed, but I am sure you are able to change this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Rinzler - here's what I got (if any one would like to play a useless 'guess a number game'). Cheers...

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, END
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class Game(Frame):
'A guessing game where a user picks a number from 1 - 100'
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Label(self, text = "Pick an integer from 1 - 100").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.answer = Entry(self, width=20)
        self.answer.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Button(self, text='Enter', command = self.compute).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.secret = randint(1,100)

    def compute(self):
        answer = int(self.answer.get())
        while self.secret != answer:
            if answer > self.secret:
                showinfo(message='Guess a lower integer')
                self.answer.delete(0, END)
                break
            else:
                showinfo(message='Guess a higher integer')
                self.answer.delete(0, END)
                break

        if self.secret == answer:
            showinfo(message='You got it! :)')
```